# What should be the network infrastructure for this mobile application?

Tags: android, networking, android-gps

We're creating an android application that can send the user's current location to another version of app used by the responders and authorities which can then display the user's location on a map interface with a marker that has the user's information. The user version transmits their location using GPS and geolocation through the internet.

And I'm having trouble creating the topology for the network infrastructure in the documentation.

Should the application both have a database and a server to store the user and location information respectively? Does it still need a database if there is already a server?

Comment: You must have a server. You can create your own server, or use cloud service as server. There are a lot cloud services can be used, eg Firebase database.

Comment: If I'm using Firebase as the server/database, should they be separate in the topology?

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase databasse .
Save locatioon and ge-location of the user of first app in the firebase .
The next another version of app used by the responders and authorities simply read the saved data from the database.